# Como Cambiar Atributos de Controles de Formulario WPF Desde Una Libreria

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, wpf

quiza esta no sea la forma tecnica de formular mi pregunta pero es que ya estoy explotando con este problema, asi que lo mostraré con una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy desarrollando una app con WPF en Visual bajo arquitectura de 3 capas, resulta que mi solucion cuenta con todas las capas, Presentacion (en este caso se llama SECOND 1.0), Logica, Datos y Entidades.
*en el pantallazo solo se ven las capas LOGICA Y PRESENTACION (SECOND 1.0)
*la capa SECOND 1.0 es un proyecto WPF en donde se encuentra el main
*la capa LOGICA es un poryecto adicional de bliblioteca de clases

mi problema es que mi formulario en la capa Presentacion (recuadro morado) tiene un boton llamado "ingreso", marcado en rojo (flecha y recuadro) y quiero que al hacerle click el color de fondo se cambie (las instrucciones ya las tengo y si lo hacía correctamente cuando trabajé con todo el codigo en una sola capa, mi problema surge al migrar a 3 capas de programacion) y no se como hacerlo, porque se supone que eso debe de hacerlo la funcion "setearBotones()" (recuadro amarillo) que se encuentra en la clase "FUNCIONES" de la capa "LOGICA"

Creo yo que la solucion sería pasarle por referencia TODO el formulario desde la capa presentacion a la capa logica y modificar ahi (con el codigo que ya tengo) el color del boton contenido en ese formulario... pero no se como...
Alguna ayuda por favor?

Comment: No entiendo bien tu ejemplo, pero si al hacer click en el botón debes usar la lógica que está en funciones pero ADEMÁS cambiar su color de fondo, pues en el evento Click del botón llama a la función que quieres y le envías por parámetro el botón mismo (el sender) y ahí puedes hacer lo que quieras con él.. En el caso que usaras MVVM podrías bindear el color del botón a una propiedad en el ViewModel y listo, pero veo que no lo estás haciendo así.

Comment: Hola, claro, estuve manejandolo asi como indicas, sin embargo cuando se da click tambien quiero que cambien colores en otros botones del mismo formulario, pero no quiero tener que pasar por parametro todos los botones, preferiría pasar por parametro todo el formulario y luego en la funcion acceder a cada boton... se puede???

Comment: Claro que se puede, solo envía "this" como parámetro y listo, todo el formulario y la clase misma se enviarán.. no se si será óptimo o será el mejor camino, eso es otra historia, pero para salir del paso si... se puede, no hay ningún problema con ello.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me sirvió el THIS pero me ayudo a descubrir que si se puede enviandole un ME en su lugar, asi que gracias, ya pude enviar todo el formulario. muy agradecido

Comment: Jajajaja si cierto, el THIS es de C#.. en tu caso es el ME.
Que bueno que te ayude, un saludo.